# Trying to display a texture but only getting a solid color with OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

My goal is to display a cube with a texture taken from a png file (DarkDirt.png). Problem is, I only get a solid brown color and my lighting is changing for every triangle forming the cube.

Now, I've been reading and I'm thinking it might have to do with setting the index to 1 but I didn't get any success with that.  I tried playing around with the UVs values but it would only change the way the lighting behaved and wouldn't fix anything. So now I'm thinking maybe my vertex (vertices in the code) are wrong?

c++ code, the arrays:

```
const GLuint NumVertices = 24;
const GLuint NumTriCubes = 12;
const GLuint NumNormals = 6;
const GLuint NumUvs = 4;

GLfloat uvs[NumUvs][2] = {
    { 0, 0 },
    { 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1 },
};

GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][3] = {
    //Front
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //0
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //1
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //2
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //3

    //Right
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //4
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, //5
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //6
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //7

    //Back
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f },  //8
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //9
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //10
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, //11

    //Left
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //12
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //13
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //14
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, //15

    //Upper
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //16
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f }, //17
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //18
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f }, //19

    //Bottom
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //20
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, //21
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f }, //22
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f }, //23

};

GLuint vertexIndices[NumTriCubes][3] = {
    //Front
    { 0, 1, 2 },
    { 0, 2, 3 },

    //Right
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 4, 6, 7 },

    //Back
    { 8, 9, 10 },
    { 8, 10, 11 },

    //Left
    { 12, 13, 14 },
    { 12, 14, 15 },

    //Upper
    { 16, 17, 18 },
    { 16, 18, 19 },

    //Bottom
    { 20, 21, 22 },
    { 20, 22, 23 }
};

GLfloat normals[NumVertices][3] = {

    //Front
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},

    //Right
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},

    //Back
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f},

    //Left
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},

    //Upper
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},

    //Bottom
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
    { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}

};
```

c++ code, I bind the texture in draw() function :

```
    m_texture->bind();
```

c++ code, initialization :

```
    glGenBuffers(NumBuffers, m_Buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Buffers[VBO_Cube]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices)+ sizeof(uvs) + sizeof(normals), nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(uvs), uvs);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(uvs), sizeof(normals), normals);

...

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(m_vNormalLocation));
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(m_vNormalLocation), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices)));

    glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(m_vUVLocation), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLuint(m_vUVLocation));

...
    m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage("DarkDirt.png").mirrored());
    m_texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapLinear);
    m_texture->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
```

I'm trying to get the texture to be displayed on every side of the cube. So it would give me a "dirt cube", like in minecraft for example. But yeah, right now it only shows up as a solid brown cube with lighting all over the place. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one texture coordinate attribute for each vertex coordinate. Since you have 24 (4*6) vertex coordinates you need 24 texture coordinate attributes, too:

```cpp
const GLuint NumUvs = 24;
GLfloat uvs[NumUvs][2] = {
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 },
    { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }
};
```

The calculation of the offset of the normal vectors is wrong:

> ```
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(uvs), uvs);
> glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(uvs), sizeof(normals), normals);
>
> glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(m_vNormalLocation), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
>       BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices)));
> ```

It has to be:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(m_vNormalLocation), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
    BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(uvs)));
```

---

It seems that the attribute index of the texture coordinates (`m_vUVLocation`) is never set in your program.

You can get the attribute index of an attribute by [`QOpenGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.12/qopenglshaderprogram.html#attributeLocation) :

```cpp
m_vUVLocation = m_programRender->attributeLocation("vUV");
```

or native OpenGL by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml):

```cpp
m_vUVLocation = glGetAttribLocation(m_programRender->programId(), "vUV");
```

Note, it is also possible to use [GLSL Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) to define the attribute location in the shader code:

e.g. Vertex shader:

```c
#version 400 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 vUV;
```

I this case the value for `m_vUVLocation` would be 3.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I've been struggling with OpenGL quite a bit lately but you helped me figure out a couple of things.